# Help with proof of distributive law in propositional logic

Tags: logic

I'm having immense trouble understanding the proof of:

$$(P \vee Q) \wedge (P \vee R) \vdash P \vee (Q \wedge R)$$

With only $(P \vee Q)$ and $(P \vee R)$ as premises, I understand that I have to assume $(P \vee Q) \wedge (P \vee R) \vdash P \vee (Q \wedge R)$ in a subproof but not what I have to do from there, that is: I don't entirely understand how $(Q \wedge R)$, or $(P)$ for that matter, is ever proven.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you have to give a formal proof or formal derivation? What rules do you have?

Comment: Do you understand intuitively why it should be true?

Comment: Why would you assume the desired assertion in a subproof?

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP does not know how to begin starting the proof, I will provide two proofs as examples using a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) that the OP can use to check that the proofs are correct and for further practice.

The first proof is a direct proof. Starting with the premise, $(P∨Q)∧(P∨R)$, I will derive the conclusion, $P∨(Q∧R)$:

[image]

On lines 2 and 3, I derive each of the conjuncts in line 1 using [conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) (∧E).

Since each of these are disjuncts, that is, two statements connected by "or", in order to use them I have to consider each of the cases and derive the same result.  I start with the first statement on line 2. I consider the $P$ case on lines 4 to 5 using disjunction introduction (vI) to add to $P$ exactly what I need to reach the goal with this case. On lines 6 to 12 I consider the $Q$ case. This is harder. To derive this I have to consider the statement on line 3 with its two cases, $P$ and $R$.

For each case, I was able to derive the desired result and so the proof succeeded.

---

The next proof approaches the the problem by assuming the same premises, but also assuming that the conclusion is false.  I need to derive an absurdity (⊥) or a contradiction between two statements for this to succeed.

[image]

The first three lines are similar to the direct proof. On line 4, I assume the negation of the conclusion is true. On line 5 I use [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) on line 4. That gives me a statement with two conjuncts. I derive each conjunct on lines 6 and 7. On line 8, I use [disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism) (DS) to derive the disjunct I need from line 2. On line 9, I do the same for line 3. After using [conjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction) (∧I) on line 10, this gives me a statement that contracts another statement, line 7. I can now derive the absurdity on line 11. On line 12, I use indirect proof (IP) to complete the proof.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Basically,  $(P\vee Q)\wedge (P\vee R)$ means $P$ or $Q$, and $P$ or $R$.

- In the case of $P$ then we clearly derive $P\vee(Q\wedge R)$.
- In the case of $Q$ then $P\vee R$ is also still true

  - We've dealt with the case of $P$.
  - In the case of $R$ (under condition of $Q$) then we derive $P\vee (Q\wedge R)$.

So all cases derive $P\vee(Q\wedge R)$.